# What is the smallest number of roads in a country?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

> There are $300$ cities in the country. Some pairs of them are
> connected by roads. It turned out that if you close any $150$ cities,
> then there will be at least $150$ roads. What is the smallest number
> of roads in a country?

**My solution**:

We take a graph with $2n$ vertices such that each $n$-vertex subgraph of it contains at least $n$ edges. Let us sum this number over all possible $n$-vertex subgraphs. The resulting number will be greater or equal to $nC_{2 n}^{n}$. Note that for each edge there are exactly $C_{2 n-2}^{n-2}$ $n$-vertex subgraphs containing it. So each existing edge appears in the sum exactly $C_{2 n-2}^{n-2}$ times. Thus, the number of roads (edges of the original graph) is greater than or equal to $\dfrac{2 n(2n-1)}{n-1}$. Therefore, the answer is $603$.

However, this is an estimate, but is there an example of such a graph with $300$ vertices?

For $4$ vertices this is an impossible situation (one cannot draw $2$ edges between $2$ vertices).

For $6$ vertices, the inequality will exactly give the number of edges in the complete graph.

For $8$, the inequality will give: ($⩾8\cdot7/3=18.6666$).

I think we can try to build a graph with $8$ vertices and $19$ edges that satisfies the properties that any $4$-vertex subgraph has at least $4$ edges. But how to do this is another question. Any ideas?

Comment: What does it mean to 'close' a city?

Comment: @Buraian This means removing a vertex of the graph along with its incident edges. In problems of this type, this kind of concept is often used, although I would talk about choosing a subgraph with a given number of vertices.

Comment: @Cornifer Specifically, an _induced_ subgraph. When picking a subgraph, you are free to choose which edges to include (as long as both endpoints are included). But with induced subgraphs, you only pick the vertices, and then by definition pick all the edges you're allowed to pick.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [There are $2n$ people on a social media platform. Prove there are at least $5n$ pairs of friends.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094730/318073)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $n$, you can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $N=\{0,\dots,2n-1\}$ be the node set, and let $E=\{(i,j)\in N \times N: i < j\}$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether edge $(i,j)\in E$ appears.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_{i,j}$$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in E: \{i,j\} \subset S} x_{i,j} \ge n \quad \text{for all $S\subset N$ such that $|S|=n$}.$$

For $2n=8$, the minimum turns out to be $23$:

```
{<0,1>,<0,3>,<0,4>,<0,5>,<0,6>,<0,7>,<1,3>,<1,4>,<1,5>,<1,6>,<1,7>,<2,3>,<2,4>,<2,5>,<2,6>,<2,7>,<3,4>,<3,6>,<3,7>,<4,6>,<4,7>,<5,6>,<5,7>}
```

Comment: This method is absolutely not feasible for the problem $2n = 300$ though. There would be $\binom{300}{150} \approx 10^{89}$ linear constraints.

Comment: @VTand I agree that explicit enumeration of all constraints is out of the question for large $n$, but you could generate them dynamically only as needed ("row generation").